# iPhone 4S Screenshots required if my app requires a minimum of iPhone 5?

Tags: app-store

Do I need to prepare screenshots for the iPhone 4S if my app can only run on the iPhone 5 and up? It's an app that is primarily used along with the Apple Watch.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't make sense to provide screenshots for an unsupported environment.

Comment: The documentation shows that 3.5" screenshots are "required". Wondering if I don't provide 3.5" screenshots, will my app get rejected?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you do have to. For understanding, you can think of the following: 
 Let's say I have an app I will set to iOS 8.1 as lowest deployment target. If there are users using iOS 7.1 they should still have to see the screenshots right?

Hope that helps :)